# Has my application been started by CreateObject?

Tags: windows, mfc, com, startup, createobject

Can I find out whether my C++ MFC COM server has been started by hand or by a call of `CreateObject()`?

Comment: Just add some argument to the command line you register for your COM exe server. For example, Excel registers `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE /automation` (in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer32`) so when started using CreateObject, it will have the /automation argument

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
I noticed that the command line switch -Embedding is added by windows (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/com/localserver32) 
Is there an advantage of your suggestion?

Comment: I didn't remember if Windows was itself always adding something (historically, not sure it did), so no, that's the same idea, you can use a command line of yours or just use what Windows does